# When is diatonic transposition useful?

Tags: transposition

Chromatic transposition, which moves each note by the same number of semitones (e.g. C E G to D F# A) is clearly useful to change the key of a song. I just heard of diatonic transposition, which moves each note by the same number of steps in the scale (e.g. C E G to D F A in C major). However, this must change up a melody or chord progression completely, right?

When is it useful to think in terms of diatonic transposition? I realise that this operation preserves the key, but what does it *do* and why is it useful? Can it still be considered the same melody or chord progression?

Comment: As always, a technique is useful when it leads you to a satisfactory musical result. Dean has given an example of diatonic transposition in the second. There is a fugue (A major for piano) by Shostakovich which has only notes from the tonic chord in its theme, and in the course of the fugue it gets transposed diatonically (scale-preserving) and even *chord-preserving* (a e a c# e a e turns into c# a c# e a c# a). The result is obviously that all voices are trivially consonant, which is what the composer wanted in this instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple use case for diatonic transposition is fugue & canon. For example, below is the opening of the 6th of the *Goldberg Variations* which is a canon at the 2nd (i.e the 2nd voice plays the same melody as the 1st, but a 2nd higher).
[image: Goldberg Variations. Var 6 - Canon at the 2nd (Czerny ed.)]
As you can see, the transposition is diatonic, rather then chromatic. One effect of this, as you have deduced, is that the 2nd voice is in a different **mode** from that of 1st. The upshot of this is that the 2nd voice continues in the same **key** as the 1st. If you were to play the 2nd voice in the Bach example in the same mode as the 1st (chromatically transposed), the music would modulate every 2 bars as statement (1st voice) caught up with the new key set by the answer (2nd voice).

If this were a fugue, the second voice being "diatonically transposed" would be called a `tonal answer` as it preserves the key of the piece, whereas if the second voice enters "chromatically transposed", thereby modulating to the key of the second voice's melody, it would be called a `real answer`, effecting a modulation to the key of the answer.